# Copying all foursquare venues of a city without violating API's usage rules?

Tags: api, foursquare

**Scope:**

I am starting an application that will need a very rich database of venues within a certain city right on it's start so i thought that scraping foursquare's database would be a great idea, but seems like scraping volumes over 1000 venues is considered forbidden according to it's [usage / data retention policy](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/venues#rules)

**My Needs:**

Basically, what i want to achieve is a way to allow users to search their favorite venues and receive notifications from them, so having all the venues of this city would be perfect for me, allowing me to store the relationship `USER XXX FOLLOWS YYY VENUE`

**Problem:**

Since i can't "copy" / "transfer" all the foursquare venues of a given city to my own database, what can i do to actually "store" the data i need for my own use ?

Is there any workaround for this ? (I don't mean ilegal actions, but some clever use of the API instead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force your users to connect with 4sq (with oauth), then retrieve the data you need using oauth tokenwith 4sq api, which does not violate the rules and put any limits to the amount of data.

You can store user's 4sq id and the venue ids they follow in your own db and retrieve the details as needed. Am I missing sth with this flow?

Comment: That's what i just thought. I could store only the Relationship on my database (user XXX follows YYYY venue), and it would work like a Foreign key to another table, but it would be a key to FS's database, right ? Is that what you thought ?

I would rather not force my users to sign up for Foursquare since here in Brasil the ammount of users using FS is not that great.